# De ascii a string C# en Windows Form con keypress - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, keypressevent

el caso es el siguiente, tengo que hacer una aplicación que tome los datos de un paciente mediante windows form, debo validar que los campos cumplan con el formato adecuado mediante expresiones regulares, el punto es que cuando disparo el evento keypress

`private void textBoxNombres_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`

recibo al parecer los caracteres en ascii en "e"

No se fijen por favor en la expresión regular se que está incompleta, el problema es que

`public bool ValidarSoloLetras(string cadena)`

"(String cadena)"No me está recibiendo lo ingresado por teclado, creo que el problema es que debo transformar el input a string pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

Aquí están los dos códigos.

````
namespace Odontologia
{
   public partial class FormRegistro : Form
        {
        public validar objValidar = new validar();

        public FormRegistro()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

                                    
            private void textBoxNombres_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
           
            bool resultado = objValidar.ValidarSoloLetras(e.ToString());
          
            if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            
        }
}```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Debe pasar lo ingresado por teclado a al siguiente código de la clase validar 



```namespace validacion
{
    public class validar
        
    {
        private Regex rgx;

               
        public bool ValidarSoloLetras(string cadena) // aquí no pasa el string, no recibe nada en el parámetro cadena, debe recibir el input.
        {
            rgx = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóú\s]+$"); // por favor no se fijen en la expresión regular debo mejorarla.
            if (rgx.IsMatch(cadena))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        
    }
}
````

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Porqué validar con cada pulsación de tecla? ¿No sería mejor validar cada campo al momento de realizar una acción como un clic sobre un botón o incluso validar cada campo al perder el enfoque? Al menos es lo que yo haría. Saludos

Comment: Similar a lo que menciona @MauricioContreras, estas validando cada carácter y tu función esta pensada para validar una cadena, aunque terminaras de escribir y cumpliera la condición siempre fallaría, por que compruebas caracter a caracter.

Si deseas de igual manera validar caracter a caracter hasta que cumpla la condición, debes ir concatenando el caracter recibido y pasando esa cadena a tu función en el evento.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentaba, tu función esta pensada para validar una cadena, entonces es mejor pasarle el valor del texBox. Tambien cambiaria el orden de comprobación que haces para saber si es una letra el caracter.

````
namespace Odontologia
{
    public partial class FormRegistro : Form
    {
         public validar objValidar = new validar();

         public FormRegistro()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

                                    
         private void textBoxNombres_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
         {
           
             if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
             {
                 e.Handled = false;
             }
                
             bool resultado = objValidar.ValidarSoloLetras(textBoxNombres.Text);     
         }
     }```
````

**Ahora esto realizará la validación por cada carater ingresado.**

Si tu intención es validarlo solo en una ocasión, es mejor llamar a *objValidar.ValidarSoloLetras()* cuando se presiones un boton o la acción que debas realizar cuando este texBox ya tenga el dato.